# Нужна ли в данном случае запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

Они не такие(,) как раньше.
С одной стороны, идет сравнение, с другой - без "как раньше" предложение уже не то предложение, да и перед "как" отрицательное слово...

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Во второй части подразумевается слово "были":

"*Они не такие, как (были) раньше*".

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, но не потому, что во второй части подразумевается "были". Запятыми выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово *так, такой, тот, столь*.

Comment: Это само собой. Но не только же в этих случаях они отделяются.

Comment: Артем, запятая нужна в любом случае. Даже если не будет ''были''.

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, предложение с придаточным уже не то, что без придаточного, и это Вас не должно смущать (см. [Пунктуация при оборотах, не являющихся придаточными предложениями](http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxix.html)).

Должно быть, Вас ввело в заблуждение правило о нераздроблении запятыми цельных по смыслу выражений ("сейчас не то что раньше"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но: *"Сейчас тут не так, как раньше"* или (Ваш пример) *"Они не такие, как раньше",* - "работает" указательное слово, о котором уже сказал Серж.

Что касается отрицания перед "как" - так оно ж не перед "как", а перед "такие" (что совсем другой коленкор).

Итак, запятая НЕ ставится, если...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сравните:

*Эти двое поступают не как добрые друзья* - *Эти двое поступают не так, как добрые друзья.*

Comment: Сержик, не поняла... Мой ОТВЕТ не по теме? Скриншотики - да, моего производства.

Comment: А-а! А это я хитрая оказалась! ))) Я ничего не умею выделять в скринах (типо заключать в рамочку или рисовать геометрическую стрелочку), так вот... Недавно меня научили, как в большом тексте найти нужное словосочетание: Ctrl + F, - искомое выделится красным, а предложение-пример я засинила, как при копировании... Вот так и родились два цвета в скрине! )))

Comment: Спасибо большое. Будем стараться учиться выделять.

Comment: Галина: *..."работает" указательное слово...* И перед этим пример: *Сейчас здесь не **то** что раньше.* Но ведь здесь тоже указательное слово есть!